# Automating attribute field completion based on closest value in a list

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes

I created the following model based on the fields that is needed for asset valuation. Please see below.[image: Add Fields: Model]

I would like to auto-populate the "Code" field basde on certain criteria, for example.

The "size" field determines the Code field: if a pipe is 110mm thick a Code of "P_1" is added to the code field. This is later used to lookup the unit rate of said pipe.

Now here is where i am stuck: I would like to write a python script that will auto populate the Code field for me but the size value is not always constant. In some cases the pipe will be attributed the size of 108mm. I would like the script to then assign the "P_1" code to this pipe as the is a 2mm difference.

Is this possible within Arcmap or will i need to use a post gis program?

Comment: It's possible with Python.
Whats your experience level with it?

Comment: Not that great. I know the basics. I assume that some loop function will be used?

Comment: Well, you need to create a switch of an if-statement in a python script. I.e. if pipeThickness > 110 { code = 'P_1' }

Comment: Thank you. Will try that. I do not only have 110mm Pipes. The list is as follows:                                                                                                             50
63
75
90
110
125
140
160
200
250
315
355
400
450
500
550
600
650
700
750
800
850
900
950
1000
1100
1200
1300
1400
1500
1600
1800                                                                                                                     The "Code" should be attributed to the closets value.

Comment: What do you mean with the closest value?

Comment: So if the value is 108mm it should bump up to 110mm but if the value the is 97 it should get the "90mm" size code and not 110mm code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36452/discussion-between-dean-van-den-heever-and-stefan).

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable using the field calculator with Python parser. The simplest way is to define a dictionary which contains the pipe type for each diameter. You could also try using if, then statements, but dictionaries are probably easier and more "pythonic".

There's a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141207/1500125) which shows how to get the closest value in a list. It can also be applied to dictionaries.

Using your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZpOx.jpg) from the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36452/discussion-between-dean-van-den-heever-and-stefan), I created a dictionary for all pipe types (Comp ID).

**Codeblock:**

```
def diameter(n):
    diamDict = {50:'W_PIP_1',63:'W_PIP_2',75:'W_PIP_3',90:'W_PIP_4',
            110:'W_PIP_5',125:'W_PIP_6',140:'W_PIP_7',160:'W_PIP_8',
            200:'W_PIP_9',250:'W_PIP_10',315:'W_PIP_11',355:'W_PIP_12',
            400:'W_PIP_13',500:'W_PIP_14',550:'W_PIP_15',600:'W_PIP_16',
            650:'W_PIP_17',700:'W_PIP_18',750:'W_PIP_19',800:'W_PIP_20',
            850:'W_PIP_21',900:'W_PIP_22',950:'W_PIP_23',1000:'W_PIP_24',
            1100:'W_PIP_25',1200:'W_PIP_26',1300:'W_PIP_27',1400:'W_PIP_28',
            1500:'W_PIP_29',1600:'W_PIP_30',1700:'W_PIP_31',1800:'W_PIP_32'}


    return diamDict[min(diamDict, key=lambda x:abs(x-n))]
```

Expression:

```
diameter( !Diam!)
```

[image]

I created a few sample lines with varying diameters and ran the field calculator on the Pipe Type field.

The results are below:

[image]

You can see that a diameter of 97 gets the value for a 90mm pipe (W_PIP_4) and a 108mm pipe gets the value for a 110mm pipe (W_PIP_5).